# How to authenticate user using Spring Security for REST API

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I I have been searching a lot for answer to this question. However after reading a lot of resources including Spring Security documentation as well I am still away from completely 
understanding as to how to authenticate a user for REST API using Spring Security  .
      Here is what I want to do:

- 1) I want to implement authentication like Amazon S3 service using public-private key
- 2) For that I will be sending an HMAC token with every request and public key in       authorization header or my own custom header.
- 3) I want to use  spring security to achieve server side handling of the token as follows:

  - 1) fetch the public key from the header.
  - 2) get the private key stored in database using my cutsom UserDetailService class
  - 3) calculate the HMAC token on server side using request and private key just like I do it on client
  - 4) compare two tokens to verify user
  - 5) if successful,store authentication object in SecurityContextHolder.

From above I am not sure how to do this in Spring Security. What I have understood is as follows:

- 1) Use a `<http>` element along with custom filter. I have done this as follows

  ```
  <http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" 
        authentication-manager-ref="restAuthenticationManager" 
        entry-point-ref="jkwebRestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()">
      </intercept-url>
      <custom-filter ref="jkWebSecurityHmacAuthenticationFilter"
       position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
  </http>
  ```
- 2) Now I can get access the header in this filter and access public key from it.
    However, I am not sure how to retrieve the private key from database using this public key. Do I need to use custom AuthenticationManager or AuthenticationProvider? and how to do this.OR can I directly inject my UserDetailService Bean into filter bean as it is?
- 3) If I do not need to use custom AuthenticationManager or AuthenticationProvider and I can inject UserDetailService  directly into filter bean,then do I need custom AuthenticationEntryPoint?
- 4) Assuming I am able to retrieve and do authentication in the filter do I need to just call chain.doFilter and request will be forwarded to the appropriate controller?
- 5) in case if authentication fails in the filter how I should 401 resonse to client or custom authentication entry point need to be used? if yes how?
- 6) also I need to put Authioities in UserDetails which I construct in UserDetailsService implementation and set it in UserDetails object. Just by setting the authentication object in security context will do the job and authorization will be carried our once authentication is successful?

I can post more code for clarity if needed.

Comment: (moving 'answer' to 'comment' section due to review comments.) Here is the best example I have found.
https://code.google.com/p/spring-rest-hmac/ which is [mirrored on GitHub here](https://github.com/ryantenney/spring-rest-hmac/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ericsson/erifly/security)

No warranty implied, proceed at your own risk, etc. I started copying over code but you should really review the whole package. It's probably a good starting point, but you'll need to work hard to make this secure I would think.